# Can the difference between exponential RVs be exponential?

Tags: self-study, random-variable, exponential-distribution, order-statistics

Let $x_1, x_2, ... x_n$ be iid exponential(1). The objective is to show that $y_i=x_{(i)}-x_{(i-1)}$ are independently distributed as exponential random variables, where $x_{(i)}$ refers to the ith order stat and $y_1=x_{(1)}$

I know that $x_{(1)}$ is exponential(n) and that correspondingly, the other  $x_{(i)}$ are minimums of the respective remaining variables once those smaller than them are removed and so they are also exponential with parameter equal to $(n-i+1)$. However, I can't see how taking the difference between 2 consecutive order stats would result in an exponential.

Comment: Try writing out the distribution for $x_i | x_{i-1}$.  Then note that $y_i = x_i - x_{i-1}$, and things should become clear.  As an additional hint, note that if you condition on $x_{i-1}$, you don't actually care about the distribution of $x_{i-1}$; at the time of conditioning, it's just a number.

Comment: @jbowman Just to clarify. Is $x_i$ there the original rvs or the order stat? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, bad notation on my part.  The order stat.

Comment: Ok. So for example, $Pr(x_{(2)}<a|x_{(1)}<a)$ isn't this just $Pr(x_{(2)}<a)$?

Comment: You want $p(x_{(2)} = a | x_{(1)} = b)$.  Assume for concreteness that your first order statistic = 3; what's the distribution of the second order statistic given that?

Comment: I don't think I follow. Isn't the distribution continuous which would mean $Pr(x_{(i)}=a)=0$? Also, if the 1st order stat is 3, then I expect the next to not have a value less than 3, right?

Comment: The density:  $f(.)$ if you prefer.

Comment: I see, sorry I got confused. So $f(x_{(2)}|x_{(1)})=\frac{f(x_{(2)},x_{(1)})}{f(x_{(1)}}$?This should be $f(x_{(2)})$ for the two to be independent, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63679/discussion-between-jbowman-and-user164144).